# Tricky website idea (not your average idea, and not a "will you program this for me?" request)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, flash, node.js

Again, to re-iterate: This is not a request to program anything for me. I am looking for more experienced web developers to tell me if my idea is really doable, as it involves some pretty tough issues (at least, I think so). Please, if this post is to be closed, could I at least get a little advice on where I should be posting instead first?

Imagine: You visit a website (say malonssite.com). You sign in, you get a double-paned window. Left side is chat list(think FB buddy list). Right side is a "browser".

The chat list is populated by other people who have signed into malonssite.com AND are visiting the same page as as you using the "embedded" browser.

Each user has the ability to "allow followers", at which point whatever site they visit, all their followers "follow".

Image sketch:
[image: sketch]

My abilities:
PHP
MySQL
Javascript (node.js included, but that's more serverish I guess)

I've done long polling and ajax, but this gets complicated. I am thinking something like this might be best done in flash? Or maybe an oldschool Java applet? I am just not sure.

I am pretty confident I can make this thing on my own, I am just not sure what technology to use. I usually hit stumbling blocks in each area, normally along the lines of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). I know that JSONP can get around the SOP, however is it powerful enough to do what I want? I am not familiar enough with it.

Sockets in general (websockets, flash sockets, etc) and node.js are pretty new to me, and I think they somehow hold the answer, I am just looking for some verification.

Thanks!

Comment: You're going to want to make this look a lot more like a question and a lot less like a short story if you want it to survive on SE.

Comment: Doable. but it does resemble 1998 AOL/compuserve software =/
"yo dawg, you heard you like browsers.."

Comment: So it's a program that allows you to talk to other people on the same website as you? Sounds pretty neat. Maybe it would work better as a web browser extension? That way I imagine you could easily get the URL of the page the user was looking at, send it to a server which is running a bespoke program (Maybe C# Service) which would then rely around users and messages etc.

Comment: @Joel Yeah, browser extension is the answer I am hearing the most, but it would be nice to not have to code and update multiple browser extensions (ie, firefox and chrome come to mind, obv.)

Comment: @MALON Yeah, defiantly I guess if you make it as a webpage people could set it as their homepage, you could do all sorts of cool stuff like the display the most active chats, have site-wide chat and page chat. I'd recomendend the use of Iframes for the browser part.

Comment: @Joel The iframe thing is tough, because as far as I could tell, I was unable to retrieve the iframe URL. That violates the same origin policy :( But there's GOT to be a way...

Comment: Not your background but check out Lift (http://seventhings.liftweb.net/)

Comment: @cyber-monk I've never heard of that framework before, but it looks incredibly promising. Their chat example: http://seventhings.liftweb.net/comet shows that they are using always-on sockets (open the chat in 2 different browsers and see how long it takes one message to get to the other browser, it's damn near instant), so that's good. Even if this framework turns out not suitable for any production work, this could still be a fantastic framework for learning or doing quick mockup work (if it's really as easy as they claim it is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it, you'll just need an iframe with a JScript asking its src and sending it to the server. So basically the user will stay on your own domain, browsing other web sites in the iframe and you will have no cross-origin-request issues.

You could use ape engine for the server side, which is exactly meant for this sort of things.

Comment: Wow! APE engine is awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for I think. if not, this is a tremendous step in the right direction! Thanks!

Comment: I'm 90% agree with Alex here. Except for [_ape engine_](http://www.cove.org/ape/), or did you mean [appengine](http://code.google.com/appengine/)? Since the idea is basically a variant of [diggbar](http://about.digg.com/blog/diggbar-launches-today), I see only 1 issue, many sites have [framebuster ready](http://daringfireball.net/2009/04/how_to_block_the_diggbar)... it's probably why _talkita_ (from Dementic's answer) go with the extension route.

Answer (score 1):

It is very possible.

Simple? no. But possible.

HTML/CSS/JS will easily take care of the front end layout,that should be elementary.

Node.js is a good option, and would be best suited if you know that traffic will be heavy.

If traffic won't be heavy, i guess php is OK.

And you will also need a backend database...again, depends on how many users you think you'll have. nosql ones would suit well, although oracle just claimed they 'exponentially' improved mySQL performance.

But think about this idea carefully. The concept of allowing users to communicate if they're on the same page is neat - but they'd have to browse a site within your site....furthermore, you have to account when the user presses next/back button in the browser.

perhaps you could make a fork of firefox and implement this as a software

Comment: Good point on the forward/back thing...I'd probably have to code in some special forward/back links, but yeah, this keeps seeming more and more likely that it would have to be either a full software set or a browser extension.

Answer (score 1):

did you mean something like [talkita](http://www.addictivetips.com/internet-tips/chat-with-people-browsing-the-same-website-in-chrome-with-talkita/)
or any other solution on google search "[chat with others on same page](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=chat+with+others+on+same+page&pbx=1&oq=chat+with+others+on+same+page&aq=f&aqi=g-v1&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=2376l3449l1l3544l9l4l0l5l5l1l167l314l0.2l3l0&gs_l=hp.3..0i15.2376l3449l1l3544l9l4l0l5l5l1l167l314l0j2l3l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=f2ebd9a574ca6fd0&biw=1920&bih=955)"?
some of them also allow followors (subscribers) etc..
have a look, maybe youll get an idea.

Comment: This was actually helpful. blerp.com is very close to what i have imagined, but not quite there yet. Thank you very much. That was such a ... simple google query, I guess i was used to googling "node js chat ajax" and stuff for far too long

Answer (score 0):

please forget about flash and java applets...
i think this is a great idea and i hope you can get it to work.
I would really use [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org) + ([Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) | [SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node)) for the server-side and realtime communication, all your SOP problems will be gone.
 As for the client side, just take care of cross browsing the javascript and css
For data persistence, some kind of [nosql](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) implementation: [mongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) or [couchDB](http://www.couchbase.com/) for example